# NoMethodError: undefined method on correct class when method DOES exist

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

As the title describes I am having an error in Rails where it is throwing a `NoMethodError` on a an instance of a class where the method DOES in fact exist.

```
NoMethodError in My#payroll_charts

Showing app/views/my/payroll_charts.rhtml where line #9 raised:
undefined method `service_managers' for #<Region:0x7f6cab0243a0>
```

As you can see this is not for a `NilClass` and is an instance of the class I DO want, the `Region` class.

The exact code causing the error in the view is:

`app/views/my/payroll_charts.rhtml`

```erb
<% region = @login.real_region %>
<% if region %>
  <% @service_managers = region.service_managers %>
<% else %>
  <% @service_managers = Region.service_managers %>
<% end %>
```

And finally, here is the `Region` class:

`app/models/region.rb`

```ruby
class Region < ActiveRecord::Base

#... skiping lines for brevity ...

def service_managers
  return self.service_mgrs.collect(&:staff).compact
end

#... brevity ...

class << self
  #... other class methods ...
  def service_managers
    r = Region.find(:all)
    return r.collect(&:service_mgrs).flatten.collect(&:staff).compact
  end
  #... other class methods ...
end
```

As you can see there are two versions of the method, the class one and the instance one.
The class level method works, eg the view code doesn't throw an error and the view renders as it should when `@login.real_region` in `nil` and `Region.service_managers` runs.
It is the instance level method that is not found.

FYI the `@login` object is an instance of the `Staff` class and `real_region` points to the `Region` class:

`app/models/staff.rb:`

```
has_one :real_region, :class_name => "Region"
```

Things I have tried:

- I have looked for other places in the project where the class may have been reopened and didn't find any
- I have also looked for different `Region` classes in different Modules which I didn't find either.
- Accessing the `region` object in the console while the view is running using `<% debugger %>`, and it still couldn't access the `service_managers` method
- Checking if the method exists when running `region.methods`, it didn't
- Swapping the order of the class and instance level methods in `region.rb` in case they were interfering with each other, no change
- Multiple server restarts
- Renaming both of the methods in all instances so they aren't named the same
- Deleting the whole `region.rb` and re-adding it (just in case changes weren't being detected)
- Computer restart
- Removing `class << self` and renaming all methods within it to `self.method_name` to make sure `class << self` was working as expected
- Some other things I probably can't remember now

This is all from some legacy code running on `Rails 1.2.3` and `Ruby 1.8.7`.

Any help would be veeeery much appreciated, thank you.

--- Update ---

After accessing the `region` object in the console while the view is running using `<% debugger %>` I tried using `region.class.instance_methods - ActiveRecord::Base.instance_methods` to essentially find which instance methods are accessible from the `region` instance and are not ones originating from `ActiveRecord::Base`
The result:

```
=> []
```

..................... So apparently zero instance methods are available that are not the ones inherited from `ActiveRecord::Base`. The mystery deepens.

Comment: Is this method new? Did you restart the server after you added it? Maybe code reloading didn't quite work back then. Aside from this, I have no clues. Need repro.

Comment: Dumb question, but what happens if you rename one of the methods so the names don't clash - does the issue persist?

Comment: I can see you are calling `Region.service_managers` but there no **class method** `service_managers` in `Region` model. The one that `Region` model has is **instance method** `def service_managers`.

Comment: @SergioTulentsev This is all legacy code that has inexplicably broken somehow so I'm currently picking up the pieces lol

Comment: @micfinnigan Yeah, tried that as well actually and it yields the same result (I'll edit and add it)

Comment: @Pavan There are two versions; using `class << self` and then defining methods is the same as using `def self.method_name`, they both make class methods

Comment: @Pavan: huh? There clearly _is_ a class method. Read closer.

Comment: @Starjams: from your list of attempted things, we can clearly see that nothing affects the server. Is it possible that you restart one server, but actually exercise another?

Comment: @SergioTulentsev My changes do affect the server, if I change my code the server will display new text or if I remove code the server will crash etc so changes are definitely going through.

Comment: @Starjams: all the weirder then :)

Comment: @SergioTulentsev You're telling me!... I have no idea how this could be happening

Comment: If you try adding a brand new method with a different name, right at the top of the `Region` class e.g `def new_thing`... is that method available from the debugger?

Comment: Try this: Before the call, check whether `region.class.instance_methods.include?(:service_managers)` is true, and if it isn't, list the contents of `region.class.instance_methods`.

Comment: @mikej Good call, I tried doing this and got the same no method error! The mystery deepens...

Comment: intriguing mystery! it does sound like it's not using the `Region` class you think it is...

Comment: @user1934428 Did this and it was false. I listed all instance methods and noticed that it didn't include some of the other methods defined in `region.rb`! I tried `region.class.instance_methods.include?` and passed in a load of the instance methods defined and it always returned false. Consider me officially confused

Comment: @mikej That was one of my first thoughts but there is no other `Region` class in the whole project so I have no idea where it could be coming from

Comment: have you got the code up on GitHub? I can take a quick look, just to see if I can spot anything?

Comment: @mikej I wish I could but it's code a project owned by my workplace so I don't think they would appreciate me putting it up publicly lol...

Comment: Are there any methods on `Region` that give any clues where it's coming from? e.g. `region.class.instance_methods - Object.instance_methods`?

Comment: This seems like a weird `autoload` issue to to me, especially mentioning an older version of Rails. I don't remember how exactly the initialization process works earlier versions of Rails, but can you try putting in `require "#{RAILS_ROOT}/app/models/region"` in the end of the initializer? Also, that will break reloading the file per request.

Comment: @Starjams: Methods can be dynamically added and removed from a class. Is the class `Region` defined in only one place, or is it opened and modified again somewhere? Alternatively: Do you have two versions of the `rb` file which you `require` to get the class loaded in your LOADPATH, and by chance the one picked up doesn't have this method defined?

Comment: @Starjams did you ever manage to get to the bottom of this?

Comment: @mikej I haven't yet... I passed it on to a more senior colleague and I'll see if he solved it and get back with an answer if I find one.
This being on Rails 1/Ruby 1.8.7 I imagine this is some kind of bug that has been long since fixed.